# Prove that all subsequential limits have been found

Tags: real-analysis

This was homework, and now we have the solutions to the homework, and I still have trouble following what's going on. We have

$(a_n) = \sin{\frac{n\pi}{4}}$

I can see intuitively the set of subsequential limits of $a_n$. What I don't understand is the proof (given by the prof) that the set of subsequential limits is exhaustive:

Let $S = \{the\ subsequential\ limits\}$ and suppose $L \not\in S$. Let $E = min\{|L-s|:s \in S\}$. Then every term satisfies $|a_n - L| \geq E$ so $\{n \in \mathbb{N} : |a_n - L| < E$ is empty. So $L$ cannot be a subsequential limit, therefore $S$ is exhaustive.

What if my intuitive set of limits is wrong? What does this even prove? First, I don't understand the proof, that's a problem. But second, even if I did, it seems like it's saying 'any finite set of subsequential limits is correct'. That's clearly garbage...

Comment: What does it mean for $S$ to be exhaustive?  What is it supposed to exhaust?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that $a_n$ can only take five values? and they are all subsequential limits?

Comment: Yes, this argument (at least the version included here) is not a good proof. In general, the fact that $\{n:|a_n-L|<E\}$ is empty only prohibits $L$ from being a subsequential limit if $E>0$. And proving that $E>0$ (indeed, even that the minimum exists) has to use some property of the sequence. Here, the property seems to be that every $a_n$ is in fact *equal* to an element of $S$. Indeed, that's how one gets from the definition of $E$ (in terms of $S$) to $|a_n-L|\ge E$.

Comment: @artificial_moonlet exhaustive was meant to mean '$S$ is the set of all possible subsequential limits' not just a subset, or a wrong set either.

Comment: @Henry yes it appears I was allowed to assume $a_n$ only takes 5 values.